# Photos in tableView from local gallery uses too much RAM

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, alassetslibrary

When I try to get photos using a URL from a local gallery I add them to a tableView using `ALAssetsLibrary()`

My code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: AllPhotosTableViewCell!
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AllPhotosTableViewCell

    let url = array[indexPath.section]["photos"] as! [AnyObject]

    if let image = cachedImages[url[indexPath.row] as! String] {        
        cell.imageViewImg.image = imageResize(image, sizeChange: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    } else {

        let nsURL = NSURL(string: url[indexPath.row] as! String)!
        var loadError: NSError?

        asset.assetForURL(nsURL, resultBlock: { (asset) -> Void in

            if let ast = asset {
                let image = UIImage(CGImage: ast.defaultRepresentation().fullResolutionImage().takeUnretainedValue())
                self.cachedImages[url[indexPath.row] as! String] = image

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    cell.imageViewImg.image = self.imageResize(image, sizeChange: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))

                })
            }
        }, failureBlock: {(error) -> Void in
            loadError = error
        })
    }

    return cell
}
```

I try to minimize the size of photos, it helps a little but it doesn't solve the problem if I need to use many photos (10 or more...)

Comment: If you are loading these images from file you don't need to cache them...  And you REALLY don't need to cache them as full size...

Comment: Not exactly the problem but related: AssetsLibrary is deprecated since iOS 8. Use Photos.framework instead, or you'll get major troubles with users who use iCloud Photo Library or other new features.

Answer (score 0):

What is `self.cachedImages`. If that's a dictionary then your code is holding ALL of your images in memory, and as you scroll your memory footprint will grow and grow. The simplest way to fix that would be to get rid of the cache dictionary entirely and load the images from the asset library every time, but that might be slow.

If you are scaling your images to display them in a table view then load the asset, open a graphics context at the target size, render the image at your thumbnail size, and cache the thumbnail image.

You might also look at using `NSCache`, which acts like a dictionary but manages flushing objects when memory gets low.